# how to use while loop to find the peak of a function

Tags: python, while-loop

Write a program that determines where the peak of the Planck function occurs in wavelength for a given temperature.  You must use a while loop to do this.

(12 pts) a) If the temperature of an object is 13,000 K, what is the peak wavelength?  Use 200 nm as your initial guess, and a step-size of +5 nm.  You cannot use the 'max' function in Python, nor should you take a derivative.  You are essentially writing your own max function.  You must solve this problem with a while loop.

I couldn't solve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

(From what I understood from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law)), the Planck function has the following properties:

1. It is always greater or equal to 0
2. It is increasing quite fast until it reaches it's max value, then it decreases.

This mean you can write a sample program that computes the Planck function for your initial wavelength guess, and then, as long as incrementing the wavelength increases the result, you keep on incrementing the wavelength. When you detect that your Planck's value starts decreasing, it means you have reached the peak.

I wrote a python script that does this, it is not optimized at all, and you need to have the Scipy package installed to make it run. It should however be sufficient to give you an idea of how to proceed.

```py
from scipy.constants import c, pi, Planck, Boltzmann
import math


# computes the value of the Planck function for the given wavelength and temperature
# if no temperature is given, it defaults to 13000
def planck_func(wavelen, temp=13000):
        return (8 * pi * Planck * wavelen)/(c*c*c) / (math.exp(Planck * wavelen / Boltzmann / temp) -1)

def find_peak():
        base_guess = 200
        step = 5
        last_value = -1
        while(last_value < planck_func(base_guess)):
                last_value = planck_func(base_guess)
                base_guess += step

        return last_value


print(find_peak())
```

I have no idea of Physics, so maybe I didn't use the correct equation from Wikipedia or the wrong constants, make sure to double check that.